# Group list into equivalency classes

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of things and a function that takes two args and says if they're equivalent, what's the most efficient way to group them into a list of sublists where each sublist is an equivalence class. Below is some code I wrote while typing up this question, but is there a better way?

```
def groupIntoEquivalencyClasses(aList, aEquals):
  tClasses = []
  for tElem in aList:
    tFound = False
    for tClass in tClasses:
      if aEquals(tClass[0], tElem):
        tFound = True
        tClass.append(tElem)
        break
    if not tFound:
      tClasses.append([tElem])
  return tClasses
```

Example Input

```
tNums = []
for tNum in range(20):
  tNums.append(tNum)
tThreeDiv = lambda x,y: x % 3 == y % 3
print(groupIntoEquivalencyClasses(tNums, tThreeDiv))
```

Example Output

```
[[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18],[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19], [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]]
```

Comment: Examples of input and ouput?

Comment: Here you go. It takes the numbers 1 to 19 and groups them by what they are when mod 3 is applied to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is fine. Using a dictionary to store representatives might be a bit cleaner:

```
def groupIntoEquivalencyClasses(aList, aEquals):
  classesByReps = {}
  for tElem in aList:
    tFound = False
    for rep in classesByReps.keys():
      if aEquals(tElem, rep):
        tFound = True
        classesByReps[rep].append(tElem)
        break
    if not tFound:
      classesByReps[tElem] = [tElem]  
      #or just classesByReps[tElem] = [] if you don't want to re-store the key/representative
  return tClasses
```

If you really need to optimize then you can modify a sorting algorithm that merges equivalent classes on comparison.